# Menus in the database. Good or bad?

Tags: menu

Can you give several indications (pro and cons) concerning the fact to put the menus of a web application inside the database?

Comment: .."menus of a web application inside the database" - I'm a little unclear about what that means. any more details?

Comment: the labels of the menus are in the database

Comment: This question is hardly constructive and cannot be clearly answered. Try providing a lot more context, requirements, and possible problems you've encountered when searching for a suitable solution.

Comment: So what have you attempted so far?

Comment: I'm not sure why menu-labels need to be in the database

Comment: me neither, in fact.. that is the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly it depends upon your requirement of your application. Its not always a good approach to bring a drill machine to make hole in sand. Every approach has some limitations and need more efforts if you do apply some alternate approaches.

In cons you can consider

1. Performance ( to prepare dynamic menu every time you load the master page also the static text less time to process in compare to dynamic)
2. Configuration will be always an issue while adding or modifying the menu
   (Always need a database guy at the time of any change)

Pros

1. Highly configurable and completely dynamic
2. Can add/remove the attribute and change the text without affecting anything in code.

We have some solutions also to overcome from the cons

1. In case of performance we can use caching but everytime the menu change you need to recycle the application pool.
2. For configuration you can provide a page to control the menu content. (No Sql guy needed)

So as I said earlier you can go either way as your application adopt easily and in much better way.

Comment: in a XML file, the menu would be also configurable and I could add and change text without affecting anything in code.

Comment: considering what you say, it is better if it is not in the database